# Questions about weak duality theorem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Following are some corollaries regarding the weak duality theorem.

1. Consider a constrained problem,
   $\min_{x \in X} f(x),$ subject to
   $g(x) \leq 0$ and $h(x) =0$.

   Its dual problem is $\sup_{u \geq 0,
       v} \theta(u,v)$, where the dual
   Lagrangian function is defined as
   $\theta(u,v):= \inf_{x \in X} \, f(x) +
       u^T g(x) + v^T h(x)$.

   In [Bazarra's Nonlinear
   Programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mw5HFRkCdQgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bazaraa%20nonlinear%20programming&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=QJ2XTeeaCMqJ0QGr-IiADA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=duality%20gap&f=false), on P264:

   > **Corollary 3** If $\inf \{ f(x): x \in X,  g(x) \leq 0, h(x) = 0 \} =
   >     -\infty$,
   >   then the Lagrangian dual function
   >   $\theta(u, v) = -\infty$ for each $u \geq 0$.
   >
   > **Corollary 4** If $\sup \{\theta(u, v): u  \geq 0\} = \infty$, then the
   >   primal problem has no feasible
   >   solution.
2. For a linear programming problem, $\min_{x \geq 0} c^T x$ subject to $Ax=b$, its dual problem is $\max_{p} p^Tb$ subject to $p^T A \leq c^T$. In Bertskas's Introduction to Linear Optimization, on P147:

   > **Corollary 4.1**
   >
   > **(a)** If the optimal cost in the primal
   >   is $-\infty$, then the dual problem
   >   must be infeasible.
   >
   > **(b)** If the optimal cost in the dual is
   >   $\infty$, then the primal problem must
   >   be infeasible.

**My questions**:

1. In Corollary 4 in Bazarra's and
   Corollary 4.1 in Bertsekas', why
   when one problem's optimal cost is
   unbounded, the other one is
   infeasible, i.e. has empty feasible
   set, instead of also having the same
   unbounded optimal cost?
2. Does Corollary 3 in Bazarra's book
   say that if the optimal cost in
   primal problem is $-\infty$, then
   the optimal cost in the dual must
   also be $-\infty$?
3. In the linear programming case, is
   Corollary 3 in Bazarra's book not
   consistent with Corollary 4.1(a) in
   Bertsekas' book, in that  the former implies that when the optimal cost in the primal is $-\infty$, then the dual problem has a non-empty feasible set (and has $-\infty$ optimal cost)?

Thanks! Also feel free to suggest to improve this post, e.g., to make it concise and clear.

Comment: Are you sure the primal is always a minimization problem? It could have changed in the course of the text.

Comment: @PEV: I think so. On Bertsekas's p 146, the first sentence on the same section it says the section is talking about the standard form of the primal problem, which is a minimization problem as written in p141 and p145 example 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Theorem 2.7.3(b) of Bazarra, the following holds: $P$ is unbounded $\implies$ $D$ is infeasible and $D$ is unbounded $\implies$ $P$ is infeasible.

From Corollary 1 on page 85 we have:  $D$ is infeasible $\implies$ $P$ is unbounded or infeasible and $P$ infeasible $\implies$ $D$ is unbounded or infeasible.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if, in Bazaraa's, Corollary 3 on p264 and Theorem 2.7.3(b) are contrary to each other? How to understand the former? Thanks!